# Syntastic for Vim: What are the required lines in ~/.vimrc? (PHP error checking)

Tags: php, vim, syntax, syntastic

I find the documents frustrating. What are the basic lines I need to add to my config file to get it working?

Comment: to get it (I assume Vim) working with what?

Comment: They're asking how to get a plugin for Vim (Syntastic) working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, nothing. If you've extracted Syntastic into your `.vim` directory, try using the `:SyntasticEnable` command within Vim to enable it for the filetype of the currently open file.

If you want to automatically turn it on for a given filetype, then you'll want to put a...

```
SyntasticEnable [filetype]
```

line in your `.vimrc` where `[filetype]` is the type of file you want to enable it for.

Comment: When I issue the command `SyntasticEnable javascript` I get `E492: Not an editor command: SyntasticEnable javascript`

Comment: I think now its **SyntasticCheck** or if you prefer you can toggle checking by **SyntasticToggleMode**