# Can't get "Syntastic" vim plugin to work

Tags: php, python, vim, syntax-checking, syntastic

I've installed [Syntastic](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736) plugin in vim. I can't get it to work. I've tried `:SyntasticEnable` but no luck. [`SyntasticEnable python` in my vimrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368208/syntastic-for-vim-what-are-the-required-lines-in-vimrc-php-error-checking) doesn't work either (in fact, it doesn't even parse the command, an error is shown when I try to add it to my `.vimrc` : `Not an editor command: SyntasticEnable python`).

How can I know what's going on? Syntastic isn't showing errors when I call it from vim. Does the first error  (`not and editor command` in my `.vimrc`) indicates something I'm unaware of?

I have in my .vimrc:

```
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*
let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list=1
```

I have a `python.vim` in `~/.vim/syntax_checkers` as well. I can already use [Pyflakes](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2441) for python files, it works **GREAT** but I would like to have Syntastic functionality in other files/extensions I need when developing applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is `pyflakes` on your environment path?  If it is not, then you must add it to your path, or modify syntax\checkers\python.vim and add the full path to the binary.
There are two lines you have to modify:

```
if !(executable("pyflakes"))
```

and also

```
let makeprg = 'pyflakes %'
```

---

In my case. I wanted Syntastic to work with PHP on my Windows machine. So I had to modify those two similar lines in php.vim to be:

```
let s:php_executable = "C:\\Uniserver\\usr\\local\\php\\php.exe"
if !(executable(s:php_executable))
```

and

```
let makeprg = php_executable . " -l %"
```

---

If your path contains spaces, you'll have to surround them in double quotes in the makeprg variable. Also with html.vim, the single quotes in makeprg must be replaced with double quotes, (you'll have to re-escape everything inside).

```
let s:libfolder = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuWin32\\bin\\"
let s:tidyexe = s:libfolder . "tidy.exe"
let s:grepexe = s:libfolder . "grep.exe"
if !executable(s:tidyexe) || !executable(s:grepexe)
```

and

```
let makeprg="\"".s:tidyexe."\" -e % 2>&1 \\| \"".s:grepexe."\" -v \"\<table\> lacks \\\"summary\\\" attribute\""
```

Comment: I'm using Linux, isn't supposed to work out-of-box? Did you try to use "SyntasticEnable" in your .vimrc and check if you get the same error as me?

Comment: It should work "out of the box" if you run pyflakes without an explicit path, i.e. just type "pyflakes myfile" in the terminal. (I don't use SyntasticEnable in my _vimrc file because that gets the same error as you.)  What file type are you using syntastic to check?  You might not have the required binaries, i.e. HTML requires tidy and Javascript requires jsl.

Comment: pyflakes is working, I'm having problems with syntastic. I'm going to look for the binaries you're saying it. Thanks!

Comment: You're right, I need the executables. I'm entering in each <syntax>.vim file in syntax_checkers dir to know which executables are used. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to make sure Vim has the right value set for $PATH?

```
:echo $PATH
```

If not, try putting this in your .vimrc:

```
let $PATH=substitute(system("echo \$PATH"), "\r\*\n", "", "g")
```

Then shutdown and restart vim.  If it works, you won't have to manually update the plugin's source files to manually include the path to the executables.

(found this via: https://superuser.com/questions/380535/getting-man-path-through-vim )