# How Do I get a syntax check to work in/with vim?

Tags: vim, syntax

This question has been asked, in one form or another, a dozen times here, and it blows my mind how not a single one actually addresses how to configure [syntastic](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736) or [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) such that it actually does what it is supposed to do (its README file is completely useless)

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319211/cant-get-syntastic-vim-plugin-to-work)

Can anyone provide some step by step instructions, or a link to such instructions. I tried to install jslint and spidermonkey, and I got nowhere.

---

I managed to get the syntax check to work (thanks to romainl). A few things I learned along the way that may help anyone with a similar problem

1. To build [Javascript Lint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/) look for the README file nested in `jsl-x.x.x/src/README.html`
2. The build instructions are `gmake -f Makefile.ref` but `gmake` is the [same thing](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=389841) as `make` so issue the command `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/make /usr/bin/gmake`
3. jsl will now be found in `jsl-0.3.0/src/Linux_All_DBG.OBJ/jsl`. To make it generally accessible do something like: `ln -s /whatever/jsl-0.3.0/src/Linux_All_DBG.OBJ /home/ForestGump/bin/jsl`. More information [here](http://ioconnor.wordpress.com/2009/05/02/javascriptlint-vim-and-ubuntu/)
4. To check that jsl actually works find a test file ( [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_externalexample)) then issue the command `jsl -process test.js`. It should list all the errors.
5. To customize your command line, add this to your vimrc file `set statusline=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you do? What works and what doesn't? Do you get error messages?

Here is what I did:

1. Downloaded the `jsl` sources from the [JavaScript Lint site](http://www.javascriptlint.com/).
2. Built `jsl` and moved it somewhere in my `$PATH`.
3. Checked if it worked by running it against a random .js file
4. Downloaded and installed Syntastic as a [Pathogen](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332) bundle.
5. Typed `:helptags /path/to/syntastic/doc` because for some reason Pathogen's automatic help tags generation doesn't work for me.
6. Read Syntastic's documentation: `:help syntastic`.

Steps 1 to 5 didn't take more than 3 or 4 minutes, maybe less.

Step 6 is obligatory, whatever new tool you try. RTFM.

I didn't have to configure anything beside these 3 lines in my .vimrc (and I believe the third is redundant):

```
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list=1
let g:syntastic_disabled_filetypes=['html']
let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
```

and customizing my statusline a bit with:

```
%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
```

EDIT

Here is my statusline:

```
set statusline=%<\ %n:%f\ %m%r%y%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}%=line:\ %l\ of\ %L,\ col:\ %c%V,\ win:\ %{WindowNumber()}\
```

Don't copy it verbatim or you'll get some errors due to the function call at the end. There is a paragraph about that in syntastic's help.

END EDIT

After all that, 10 or 12 minutes if you count reading the documentation, I have a very helpful location list and signs poping up each time I save a .js file with syntax errors.

Comment: I passed step 1), but how do I build it? There's no config file, make file, or even a README file (or anything on the website)

Comment: OK I found the README file in the src directory, now I have to go install a command called `gmake`

Comment: I am not sure if what I did works, I don't understand what to do with `%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}`. Does that go in my vimrc file? It generates an error when I put it there. It does not look like a command

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I'll edit the question with some additional information for anyone else that comes across this.

Comment: The `%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}` goes into your statusline. See my edit.

Comment: I'm very grateful for your help, but I want to point out that 10 or 12 minutes is best case scenario. Worst case is 6+ hours. Someone might not know what `gmake` is, someone could do everything right, but not correctly set the statusline. Maybe they don't know that they have find the jsl binary and make it accessible to PATH... It's definitely no `sudo apt-get install`

Comment: I agree it's not very easy or straightforward. Tinkering with this, hacking that is something I enjoy a bit too much, actually. Most of what relates to augmenting Vim's functions tends to be very hacky. The "hacker type" loves it but other users accustomed to other editors like NP++ or TextMate may find it frustrating.

Comment: I actually started using vim 2 days ago! I have a lot of experience with Unix so it wasn't a culture shock. Since you're a hacker, do you have any other upgrades to vim you'd recommend?

Comment: Hoho, don't go too fast. I wouldn't say I'm a hacker, I reserve this name to people a lot better than me. Has a wannabee hacker, though, I'd recommend to modify Vim the less possible. However, beside Syntastic I would recommend SnipMate, Sparkup, Surround, either Taglist or Tagbar and VCSCommand.

Answer (score 2):

Setup vundle according to its [README](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle).

Put this into your .vimrc:

```
Bundle 'scrooloose/syntastic'
```

Then enter this command in vim:

```
:BundleInstall
```

That's it.

EDIT: Vundle has changed its syntax since I originally wrote this. Nowadays, you use

```
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
```

and then enter

```
:PluginInstall
```