# Syntastic in Vim claims function might fail to return

Tags: javascript, vim, syntax, jslint, syntastic

EDIT: Syntastic is configured to use JSLint

EDIT2: I am using JavascriptLint, not JSLint

On the below code syntastic warns `function inside does not always return a value`

```
function(){
 switch(age){
 case 1:
  return 'won';
 case 2:
  return 'too';
 case 3:
  return 'tree';
 default:
  throw 'wow man, you are old!';
  break; //technically redundant
 }
}
```

I realize `default` does not return a value, but the `throw` ends the execution. Is this a Syntastic error, or should I change my coding style? Should I put a `return` statement after `throw`?

Comment: Syntastic just uses GCC to syntax check. If you compile with GCC using `-Wall` do you get the same warning?

Comment: I built my syntastic to work with jslint (described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926356/how-do-i-get-a-syntax-check-to-work-in-with-vim)).

Comment: If I use `jsl -process` I get the same problems. Isn't `gcc` for C/C++?

Comment: You're right, GCC is totally unrelated to your question.

Comment: Whoops, I'm sorry about that. Point is since JSlint is giving you that warning, and that's what syntastic is using, it can't help it. It may be a bug in JSlint, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactic uses [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html) under the hood to check Javascript syntax.

JSLint is known to be overcautious in order to avoid errors. You can either ignore the message to your better judgement, or turn off this particular warning, or add a redundant `return` there.

Personally I prefer to satisfy JSLint's requirements over turning off warnings. Just make sure to add a `//Satisfying JSlint` comment near the `return` so other people will understand the redundancy.

Comment: Thanks. I have also noticed that JSLint is over-cautious . For example it complains when `++` is used as a part of a bigger statement like so `var x=0;flags={a:x++ , b:x++ , c:x++...}`

Comment: Is there a way to turn off the warning in JSLint, just for that piece of code?  I've seen many static analysis tools that have such a feature...

Comment: Actually, found my own answer: Yes it does - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599859/jslint-control-comments-selective-ignore

Comment: Yes, because the global purpose of JSLint is to make you use only the 'good parts' of Javascript, by Crockford's definition. It's not just a syntax checker, but an *opinionated syntax* checker.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham thanks for the link. I also realized I meant Javascript Lint, not JSLint (but your link has information on both)