# Checking PHP with vim-Syntastic on Windows

Tags: php, windows, vim, syntastic

I installed Syntastic with pathogen for Vim.
I'm coding PHP on Windows,
when I type `:SynasticInfo`, I have no checkers available.

I can run `php -l index.php` on my terminal but when I run `:!php -l %` in Vim, another terminal opened with this error message:

```
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c (php -l)
'php' isn't a system command etc..
```

I found these on the web:

- https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/167
- [Syntastic for Vim: What are the required lines in ~/.vimrc? (PHP error checking)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368208/syntastic-for-vim-what-are-the-required-lines-in-vimrc-php-error-checking)

but they didn't solve my problem.

Any ideas? Thank you.

---

I installed PHP of course and my `PATH` is correct too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not installed php, you should do it by installing [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org) or [PHP](http://www.php.net/) itself, find `php.exe` in the subdirectories and add the path of it to [PATH variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

Comment: The path of php.exe is in PATH if you do echo $PATH inside vim? i don't know, when i type "echo $PATH" in vim, vim writes "$PATH" :x

Comment: Hmm... What happens if you type `:!calc`? (it should open calculator) If it not works then something with your `PATH` variable causes the problem. Try to set it inside .vimrc to be the same as on your system. (`let $PATH = 'output of 'echo %PATH%' in cmd.exe`')

Comment: :!calc open calculator

Comment: Try to disable .vimrc (`gvim -u NONE file.php`), .gvimrc (`gvim -U NONE file.php`) and the plugins (`gvim --noplugin file.php`) and call `:!php -l %`. If the `php` executing, then one of these files causes the problem, you have to check that manually. For example if the .vimrc is the badguy, then try to comment the half of it and open the file in normal way with vim. If there is no probrem while calling `:!php -l %`, then the problematic line is in the commented part of it, thus you may to comment only the quarter of the .vimrc and so on...

Comment: my Terminal says "gvim not found" when i try your commands, here is my PATH "C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16;C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\gvim;"

Comment: o_O `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\gvim`: you have to add only the PATH, not the executable itself. If i'm right `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\gvim` is an exe, so you should add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74` to $PATH. Maybe the same problem with `php`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Problem came from this line in my _vrimc that i added to try to solve the problem : let $PATH=substitute(system("echo \$PATH"), "\r\*\n", "", "g"), i have not enough reputation to vote up :(

Comment: I'm happy to help you. :) Just click on the white pipe under the vote-counter to accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

To save other's hunting through comments...

From [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851057/checking-php-with-vim-syntastic-on-windows#comment36810711_23853517):

> Problem came from this line in my `_vimrc` that I added to try to solve the problem:

`let $PATH=substitute(system("echo \$PATH"), "\r*\n", "", "g")`

As a result this was the `PATH`:

`"...C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16;C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\gvim;"`

Which as [@bimlas points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851057/checking-php-with-vim-syntastic-on-windows#comment36810231_23853517) is pointing directly at the executable files rather than the directory that they're contained in.